# 'loss nan' in time-series classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a transformer model almost exactly the same as in the Keras example code for time series data. I'll take for stock info process for practice a classification via transformer, targeting a simple {0,1} separation as result. The problem here is all I get is always loss `nan` without any accuracy improvement. please see my model:

```
def transformer_encoder(inputs, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout=0):
    # Attention and Normalization
    x = layers.MultiHeadAttention(
        key_dim=head_size, num_heads=num_heads, dropout=dropout
    )(inputs, inputs)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    res = x + inputs

    # Feed Forward Part
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=ff_dim, kernel_size=1, activation="relu")(res)
    x = layers.Dropout(dropout)(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(filters=inputs.shape[-1], kernel_size=1)(x)
    x = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(x)
    return x + res



def build_model(
    input_shape,
    head_size,
    num_heads,
    ff_dim,
    num_transformer_blocks,
    mlp_units,
    dropout=0,
    mlp_dropout=0,
    n_classes=0,
):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = inputs
    for _ in range(num_transformer_blocks):
        x = transformer_encoder(x, head_size, num_heads, ff_dim, dropout)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format="channels_first")(x)
    for dim in mlp_units:
        x = layers.Dense(dim, activation="relu")(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(mlp_dropout)(x)
    outputs = layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")(x)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs)


model = build_model(
    training_input_data[0].shape,
    head_size=10, 
    num_heads=4,
    ff_dim=2,
    num_transformer_blocks=8,
    mlp_units=[128],
    mlp_dropout=0.4,
    dropout=0.25,
    n_classes=num_class
)
```

Below shows how I compile and run to fit the model:

```
model.compile(
    loss="categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5),
    metrics=["binary_accuracy"],
)
callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)]

model.fit(
    training_input_data,
    training_output_data,
    epochs=EOPCHS,
    batch_size=32,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_split=0.1
)
```

please note that all the training data is normalized as below example (a small slice of the whole dataset). The 'date' colume is actually poped off before turning data into numpy ndarray.
[train data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Foalo.jpg)

The result of training is like:

```
Epoch 1/200
1049/1049 [==============================] - 22s 17ms/step - loss: nan - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/200
1049/1049 [==============================] - 17s 16ms/step - loss: nan - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 3/200
1049/1049 [==============================] - 17s 16ms/step - loss: nan - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 4/200
1049/1049 [==============================] - 17s 16ms/step - loss: nan - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 5/200
1049/1049 [==============================] - 17s 16ms/step - loss: nan - binary_accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: nan - val_binary_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 6/200
  59/1049 [>.............................] - ETA: 16s - loss: nan - binary_accuracy: 0.5000
```

Seems that categorical_crossentropy loss should be ok for as simple as a 0-1 classfication, outputting from the last layer of softmax. The model seems like it has learned nothing at all ---- the acc stuck at 0.5 all the way for a 0-1 job.

Any ideas?

Comment: how big is your dataset ?

Comment: input shape is: (37286, 14, 9)
Is it too small for the training?

Comment: We don't put dropout layers by default (they can be detrimental for the training), only if we suspect overfitting; but this is not a *programming* question.

Comment: All right, will try to remove the dropout in encoder loop. Am also trying some new policy to obtain training data, hope to get more. Anything else?

Comment: And, do you recommend to remove the dropout after the multihead attention, or the ones in  feed forward? or both? I'lll make a try anyway.

Comment: Removing dropout layers didn't change the situation.

Comment: BTW I've tried smaller learning rate, from 1e-4 down to 1e-7, to get all the same. Does it mean that the data itself could be the problem? Say, maybe there is NO featuer in there at all......am I fighting with a ghost?

Answer (score 0):

without having your data it is just a guess. You say that you want to make a **binary prediction** but you use "categorical_crossentropy" as your loss function which is normaly used for multiple classes. You can have a look here how and when to use diffrent loss and activation functions [Click](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/) or [Click2](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-binary-cross-entropy-log-loss-a-visual-explanation-a3ac6025181a).

So the solution for you might be:

```
model.compile(

loss="binary_crossentropy",
optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5),
metrics=["binary_accuracy"])`
```

Another thing you might look into is your activation function.You could try to use the sigmoid function and not the softmax function, to get prediction values between (0,1).